# Mobile Automata Colors

Tags: plotting, cellular-automata

Why this code does not generate a mobile automaton plot with color white when the status of the individual cells is 1?

```
 ResourceFunction["MobileAutomatonPlot"][
 ResourceFunction["MobileAutomaton"][{7, 37}, {ConstantArray[0, 15], 
   7}, 10], Mesh -> True, ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White}]
```

It only works for when they are 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation code of the [`MobileAutomatonPlot`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MobileAutomatonPlot/) resource function contains the following snippet:

```
With[{da = evol[[All, 1]]},
  ArrayPlot[da/2, PlotRange -> MinMax[da], opts]
]
```

where `evol` is the function's first argument, so what's really been plotted is the $\text{input}/2$. Since your input contains $0$ and $1$, the input to the underlying plotting function, `ArrayPlot`, will contain $0$ and $1/2$.

You need to take that transformation into consideration when you formulate your `ColorRules` patterns, i.e. to include rules for $1/2$ in lieu of $1$:

```
plot = 
  ResourceFunction["MobileAutomatonPlot"][
    ResourceFunction["MobileAutomaton"][{7, 37}, {ConstantArray[0, 15], 7}, 10],
    Mesh -> True,
    ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1/2 -> White}
  ]
```

[image: with white tiles]

An alternative would be to specify a rule for 0, and then a default value as a catch-all for any non-zero value in `ColorRules`: `ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, _ -> White}` would give the same output. I am not sure if 1 is the only other value of interest though. I am also not sure why this transformation was deemed necessary by the authors of the resource function, but then again I am not familiar with automata.

---

The disks representing the active cells are generated as `Disk` objects in a `Graphics` statement, so their color can be changed by post-processing the plot as follows:

```
plot /. d_Disk :> {Green, EdgeForm[Black], d}
```

[image: same plot, but disks are green with black edge]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solves it. Also, would you happen to know if it is possible to easily change the color of the disk representing the active cell?

Comment: @FelipeAmorim Yeah it's pretty easy to post-process the plot to change the color of the disks. See my updated answer above. The code of `MobileAutomatonPlot` is simple, so you may be able to reuse it to make your own function that takes the color of the disks as one of the arguments as well.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!